# What easing library should I use in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

Does anyone know if some sort of animation easing library like the tween libraries for Flash ActionScripting exist for c#. I've done some Google-searches but i've only found http://theinstructionlimit.com/flash-style-tweeneasing-functions-in-c and i'm looking for a more complete library. Is easing known by another name in c#-programming?

Comment: SL4 and WPF4 have Easing built-in.

Comment: Silverlight is not really an option yet. I'm building a plugin for Rhino and as far as I know only WinForms is supported. But perhaps it's possible to host WPF on a Winforms App? And SL4?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

WPF / Silverlight is the way to create animations in the .NET stack.

Comment: If WPF /SL4 is not an option, what would you recommend then?

Comment: It is possible to host WPF/Silverlight in winform, search for "Hosting WP in winform"

Comment: Perhaps it is i'm gonna look into this. Thanks

Comment: downvoting because it doesn't answer the OP's question. OP is looking for an easing library with which to apply easing to winforms elements, not hosting WPF within Winforms.

Comment: @shellscape interesting point, but it does not consider the fact the OP accepted the answer as valid.

Comment: This answer should have been a comment. Downvoting as well. If you want to improve this answer I'll gladly remove the downvote.

Comment: Also, if given a Winforms project and one of the requirements was easing you seriously would pull in the WPF framework? You claim to be a Senior Architect. It's stuff like this that makes those titles nothing more than titles.